# Determining whether Rails environment was loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I determine whether Rails has loaded the full environment or not? E.g., that the environment-specific config has fully loaded.

My underlying problem is that I'm installing a hook to capture certain exceptions in the environment-specific config, but I don't want to catch any exceptions while the config is still being loaded so as not to mask any config issues.

I found some unsatisfying ways to do this, for example `Rails.application.config.middleware` will be a `MiddlewareStackProxy` instance before the config is fully loaded (and `MiddlewareStack` after), but there must be a more direct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the order of the loading and it seems to me you need set your own environment variable perhaps after the "initializers are done" then in your code check if that is set.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/configuring.html

```
Preinitializers
environment.rb
Environment-specific Configuration Files
Initializers (load_application_initializers)
After-Initializers
```

Because of what you doing, i see no other way but to digest this part of the docs (see around 1.14):
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#config-environment-rb

Comment: Thanks, but my tasks do depend on environment, that's not the issue. Because of the framework-y code I'm writing (capturing exceptions thrown by Rake tasks), I really need to know whether the environment has loaded from any point within the load sequence.

Comment: So if your code depends on env and env has loaded because your condition is dependent on that then what's the issue? What values in the env do you need to check?

Comment: This is not about average Rake tasks, I'm hacking Rake itself. You can actually see what I'm doing [here](https://github.com/nikhaldi/exception_notification-rake). My code monkeypatches Rake to capture exceptions. However, as soon as the monkeypatch is in place, which happens during environment loading, it will capture any exceptions. I don't want that, I only want to capture exceptions once the environment finished loading.

Comment: Thanks. A reasonable way to achieve what I wanted was to use after-initializers (with `Rails.application.config.after_initialize`).